# PHP regular expression if escaped parenthesis exist

Tags: php, regex, escaping

In PHP I am trying to complete a simple task of pulling some information from a string using `preg_match_all`

I have a string like this for example `0(a)1(b)2(c)3(d)4(e)5(f)`

and I am trying to return all the contents inside of each `()` BUT having respect for the fact that escaped parenthesis might exist inside of these.

I have tried multiple combinations but I just can't get any regular expression to allow for something like this `4(here are some escaped parens\(\) more text)` to return this `here are some escaped parens\(\) more text` rather than this `here are some escaped parens\(\)`

I have a regular expression that works, but not with escaped parenthesis

`[0-9]*\(([^ESCAPED PARENTHESIS])*?\)`

Can someone give me an idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd need to look for `/\\\(/`. the first two backslashes will parse down to a single literal backslash, and the `\(` will become a regular parentheses, not capturing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [*negative look behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make your regex engine just match the close parenthesis which doesn't precede with backslash:

```
\((.+?)(?<!\\)\)
```

See Demo https://regex101.com/r/oU9sF2/1

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YB8WRy021OtCw2PR)

Comment: Perfect! I was looking into negative look behind under other stack overflow questions but I was unable to implement it correctly because the examples were for strings and I didn't quite understand how it worked. This definitely helped me figure it out. I will count this as the answer as soon as It allows me to.

Comment: My regex is almost twice as faster. No look-behind is necessary here, it only hampers performance.

Comment: @SpencerMay You can also check the related link about looking around to learn more about this topic.

Comment: I have only rely on 2 things right now: 1) number of steps to complete the match on regex101.com, 2) lazy dot matching has never been quicker than negated character class based solutions. Also, [your regex will fail here](https://regex101.com/r/oU9sF2/2), when the final `)` is preceded with two backslashes that mean 1 literal backslash (same as anubhava's).

Comment: @SpencerMay - please do be careful not to have a double back slash (escaped backslash??) ``\\`` at the end of a parenthetical target, because that will break this regex -- e.g. `0(a)1(wordsending in backslash \\)2(b)3(c)`

Comment: @stribizhev Indeed.My regex doesn't match that case but that is exactly what OP wants.But about the performance I'm with you, but it's just a good choice for large data, and for a simple or small data we can use the look around which is more concise and elegant.

Comment: @CodeJockey  Indeed.My regex doesn't match that case but that is exactly what OP wants.

Comment: @CodeJockey the contents in each `()` go through a custom function to make sure they are only escaped once. Thank you for the tip though.

Comment: it's not that the parentheses might be escaped - it's that there may, at some point in the future, be an escaped backslash ``\\`` just before the _unescaped_ parentheses that _should_ be the end of the parsed value. unless you can guarantee that will never ever ever happen :-D --- I'm just saying beee cuurfull

Comment: @SpencerMay - what does that custom function do with backslashes (``\``) in the contents of each `()`?

Comment: @CodeJockey what I mean is that before the data is inserted into the `()` the string is checked to make sure `\)` exists as a "standalone"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match your text:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\\)\((.*?)(?<!\\)\)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aK0vC2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working regex:

```
[0-9]*\(([^()\\]*(?:\\.[^()\\]*?)*)\)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT4aM7/1)

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/DiKkhW):

```
$re = '~[0-9]*\(([^()\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^()\\\\]*?)*)\)~s'; 
$str = "0(a)1(b)2(c)3(d)4(here are some escaped parens\(\) more text)5(f)"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Regex breakdown:

- `[0-9]*` - matches 0 or more digits
- `\(` - matches a literal `(`
- `([^()\\]*(?:\\[()][^()]*?)*)` - matches and captures

  - `[^()\\]*` - 0 or more symbols other than `\`, `(` and `)`
  - `(?:\\.[^()]*?)*` - matches 0 or more sequences of...

    - `\\.` - escaped character followed by
    - `[^()\\]*?` - as few as possible characters other than `\`, `(` and `)`
- `\)` - matches a literal `)`

Comment: I rolled back, it won't now.

Comment: hmmmmmmm - not sure why I pasted your regex there - now it's breaking on ``\)`` ([see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eD6nH9/2))

Comment: Don't believe @CodeJockey comments (sorry), because these example strings are wrong (when you want to escape something in the subject string in regex101, you only need one backslash, not two).

Comment: @CodeJockey: yes, in the subject string `\\)` isn't an escaped closing parenthesis, it's an escaped backslash followed with a closing parenthesis (non escaped).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte correct - in a comment on the selected answer, stribizhev pointed out that an escaped backslash (``\\``) just before the correct closing parentheses will break the expression (that is, the other expression would have seen the slash before the parenthesis and ignored it as escaped, even though it was escaped itself)

Comment: @CodeJockey: Ok, I think [it is working as expected](https://regex101.com/r/kT4aM7/1) now.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I commented that the expression here did the same for a time. It has now been changed, but was changed so that it does not do what the OP requested, which was to ignore escaped parentheses (``\)``)

Comment: @stribizhev -- better :-D -- I would personally still prefer it to not get tripped up on unescaped open parens, but that's not what the OP specified - it is implied all parens that should be ignored will be escaped (both open and close parens)

Comment: @CodeJockey: opening parenthesis have no reason to be escaped outside parenthesis.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte -- I would agree - I was talking about unescaped open parens _inside_ the parentheses ([see this example](https://regex101.com/r/kT4aM7/3)) -- if the value that is supposed to be in the set of parentheses is somehow ``wordsending in backslash\)\) \\\)2(b`` (which is probably not going to happen), then this regex will fail to capture that text, because it contains an unescaped open parens - I'm talking about a very very edge case that seems to be implied to be impossible according to what the OP explained

Comment: @CodeJockey: Sorry, but there is a boar in my living room, and I try to hunt him with a spear. I will consider your comment after (if I survive).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~[0-9]+\([^)\\]*+(?s:\\.[^)\\]*)*+\)~
EOD;
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT4eW2/1)

The idea is to match all characters until the closing parenthesis and the backslash. When a backslash is reached, the next character is matched too, and "und so weiter", etc., until the end of the world (or a closing parenthesis), all characters that are not a closing parenthesis or a backslash are matched.

Note: possessive quantifiers `*+` are only here to limit the backtracking when there is no closing parenthesis.